# Angular promise resolves inside function but not outside

Tags: angularjs, promise

I have a recursive function checking for some data every half second or so. The function returns a promise. Once I find the data, I want to resolve the promise and pass the data as the resolution. The problem is, the promise won't call .then() outside of the function. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/btyg1u0g/1/.

Here's the fiddle code:

Service:

```
myApp.factory('myService', function($q, $timeout) {

    var checkStartTime = false;
    var checkTimeout = 30000;

    function checkForContent() {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        // simulating an $http request here
        $timeout(function () {

            console.log("Checking...");

            if (!checkStartTime) checkStartTime = new Date();

            // this would normally be 'if (data)'
            if ((new Date()) - checkStartTime > 3000) {
                deferred.resolve("Finished check");
                checkStartTime = false; // reset the timeout start time
            } else {
                // if we didn't find data, wait a bit and check again
                $timeout(function () {
                    checkForContent();
                }, 400);
            }

        }, 5);

        // then is called in here when we find data
        deferred.promise.then(function(message) {
             console.log("Resolved inside checkForContent");
        });

        return deferred.promise;

    }

    return {
        runCheck: function() {
            return checkForContent()
        }
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, myService) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';

    // then is never called
    myService.runCheck()
    .then(function (message) {
        console.log("Resolved outside checkForContent");
    });

});
```

Comment: its calling the one inside checkForContent. its not calling the one in the controller. I should be seeing two logs: "Resolved inside checkForContent" and "Resolved outside checkForContent".

Comment: You are doing it wrongly.. You are never resolving the promise that you returned initially. Everytime the function creates a new promise and the last one gets resolved for which you have chained it inside your function. But the promise that was returned during the function call was never resolved.

Comment: ahh, i see, i didn't realize i was creating a new promise every time. I think you have it, but let me test.

Comment: `function checkForData(){ return $q.when().then(function poll(){ return data || $timeout(400).then(poll); })` - fixed that for you. No reason for that code to be more than 3 lines long. `$timeout` already returns a promise, promises chain and you have a deferred anti pattern.

Comment: @RobbyAllsopp Are _[you looking for a retry logic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438396/re-use-http-request-with-retry-logic-in-angularjs/25438626#25438626)_? something like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/S6oIeF?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/byzhu62g/2/).

The outter `$timeout` function is named so it can be called from within itself.

```
$timeout(function inner() {
  // ...
```

Then it is called recursively like this:

```
$timeout(function () {
  inner();
}, 400);
```

Comment: So clunky :S Look at my code sample from the comment above.